# How to install Gerrit on ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: git, gerrit

Can someone post some simple tutorial how to install and configure git with gerrit on Ubuntu 11.04  via command line.
I found this tutorial:
http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.0/install.html

But I can figure out how do I have to setup a DB. Do I have to create a seperate user for each who will commit to the repository?

If you have some useful links or advises or even want to post tutorial( I hope you do :) ) please share it with me.

Now I initialized gerrit, but only message what I got afterwards was:

```
Initialized /home/administrator
```

And no  *.sh file was created. What am I doing wrong?

Ok, if someone is reading this link, I want to  update with status. 
 I managed to install and run Gerrit on Ubuntu ( on http ), but from time to time I got internal server error when I navigate throught web UI. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: The tutorial, you already use can be followed step-by-step, so there is no other tutorial available.

Answer (score 1):

During database set up **you create a user for Gerrit connection with database**. This is completely different thing, than user accounts.

You create only one such user (as this is presented in install instruction) and it's used to authenticate connection with database.

[Later](http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.0/install.html#administrator_setup), you create user administrator account. Next **user accounts can be created using a web browser**.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it helped me to clarify all thata user stuff.

Comment: so one more questions, just to clarify, after I created this one root user and set site path, I should be able to access gerrit via borwser just by typing host name ?

Comment: Yes. (you have to start the gerrit daemon, but I think you already did)

Comment: NO(. I stuck on the step which says that I need to initialize the Schema. To bad the link which was posted above dont have any explanation why should I do some particular step.

Comment: It keeps telling me, that permission is denied when I am trying to execute  "sudo java -jar gerrit.war --cat extra/GerritServer.properties_example >GerritServer.properties"

Comment: That means you hav no permission to access something. Please paste full error message (and try to read it and understand by yourself)

Answer (score 0):

**Non-official package from [gerritforge](https://www.linkedin.com/company/gerritforge-llp)**, a Gerrit service company:

```
echo 'deb mirror://mirrorlist.gerritforge.com/deb gerrit contrib' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gerritforge.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1871F775
sudo apt-get update
sudo /etc/init.d/gerrit start
firefox http://localhost:8080
```

Currently running Gerrit 2.12.

You can create and switch to infinitely many accounts, including admin, without password, from the top left corner `Become` link.

Tested on Ubuntu 15.10.